# Latest recpatcha for node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, recaptcha

How to use the [latest captcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html) from google for node.js ?!

I know how to use [this](https://github.com/aldipower/nodejs-recaptcha)(explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132531/captcha-creation-for-nodejs)), but I don't know how to use [latest captcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html) on the server side of node.js.

Only on the client side:

1. Adding this(Client-side):

   ```
   <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
   <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="public_key"></div>
   ```
2. Adding on server side, they write:

> If your users send the form with integrated reCAPTCHA, you will receive among other things, a string containing the name "G-recaptcha-response". If you want to find out if Google has verified the user in question, send a POST request with the following parameters:
>   URL: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify
>   secret (needed) ...
>   Response (required) value of 'g-recaptcha-response'
>   remoteip The IP address of the end user
>   On the reCAPTCHA documentation website you will find more information and advanced configurations.

The problem here is, I don't know how to do this securely with node.js and by the way I could not find "G-recaptcha-response" in the response.

Can you give me informations on it ?

I am using Express.js and handlebars.js.