# Generate Captcha with pure JavaScript in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, captcha

Kind of similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132531/captcha-creation-for-nodejs/22069166#22069166), but he does not specified need pure JavaScript. I say "with pure JavaScript" means using no native (C++) modules. Any solution?

Comment: Aren't the npm modules given as answers for that question pure javascript?

Comment: @Tyler npm also includes a lot of native modules. I do not want to install C++ compiler in our work flow.

Comment: This is either an offtopic library request, or way too broad. Can you narrow it down to what part of the captcha creation you are having problems with?

Comment: Seems to me like a homework assignment.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I just cannot find any module that let me draw stuff, like GD in php. Basically, I just need to draw text, rotate, skew or draw random points or lines etc...

Comment: @Bergi Oops, I was think about to ask for a png library for my captcha system. Somehow I just put captcha here. My mind was not clear.  Should I edit the question?

Comment: @Deryck Oops, I was think about to ask for a png library for my captcha system. Somehow I just put captcha here. My mind was not clear. Should I edit the question?

Comment: @SCLeo: So you're kinda looking for [node-gd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gd), but want to avoid a C++ backend?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate PNG image using node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12380841/1048572) or [How to create an image on the fly with Node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7062812/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi I did an one-hour research, I can only find [captchapng](https://www.npmjs.com/package/captchapng) which is too simple, [node-gd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gd) which needs C++ to build and some other online generate methods that I do not really prefer.